# How should JVM/Swing GUI application show console?

Tags: java, swing, logging, console

The application creates and displays various Swing widgets, and also writes debugging messages to System.out. If I start it as `java -jar ...jar` then I see it, but if I click on jar file in GUI I don't see the console. How to make it show console to user explicitly, e.g. on reaction to "View -> Debug output" menu item?

Expecting something that will pop up cmd.exe window on Windows, xterm/... on Linux, but it may be Swing window as well. How to do it the easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [don't use `System.out` to log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601831/do-not-use-system-out-println-in-server-side-code/8601886#8601886), use some Logging framework to write logs in some file and to display the debugging logs open a new JDialog with JTextArea or JTextPane in it. Read the log file content and display that in the textArea. This way it will also solve platform dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you looking for  `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F1` works if is GUI visible here you can see output to the console, with `Tree` hierarchy of `JComponents`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK on Windows the console would be displayed on the first console output (i.e. System.out.printXXX), while on Linux it must be executed from console itself to do so. I'd rather create a separate window with a JTextArea (or something similar) to display the debug output. Normal users won't care about / need it, right?

Comment: No, in Windows it does not pop up the console on output to it. Probably will use more proper logger and JTextWhatever log window.

Comment: Hmm... it does on my XP, if the interpreter used is java instead of javaw.