# Logging information in the console --java

Tags: java, logging, system.out

I have a command line application and my client needa the debugging information in the command line. I would like to add the debugging information using `System.out.println`, as in

```
System.out.println("message");
```

Is this good programming practice? Otherwise, what would be a better option?

Comment: Actually this is very bad practice. Use a logging framework like `log4j` for this.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here to know why syso is not preferred: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601831/do-not-use-system-out-println-in-server-side-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `System.out.println()`, use a logging framework.

There are several logging frameworks that are used for Java projects. [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) is probably the most well-known and popular one. My first choice would be [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), which is actually not a logging framework itself, but a layer which you use to which you can plug-in different logging frameworks (such as Log4J or [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)).

There's also a standard logging framework in the standard Java API, in the package `java.util.logging`, but in my experience it isn't very popular.

Advantages of using a logging framework instead of `System.out.println()` calls are that you can easily configure the logging to write to a file or some other storage instead of to the console, and that you can use different logging levels for debugging, warnings, and errors, and you can choose what level of log output you want to get.