# Hibernate show sql is equal to Stdout

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x

I declared `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in hibernate. I read stdout issues in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601831/do-not-use-system-out-println-in-server-side-code). Stdout will consume more memory. So How **show_sql** functionality will working?. Because of I have seen in server log stdout sql query.

```
13:06:53,323 INFO  [stdout] (http-/172.29.250.43:8080-7) Hibernate: select sampledata0_.idsample as idsample4_10_1_, sampledata0_.id as id1_9_1_, sampledata0_.id as id1_9_0_, sampledata0_.idsample as idsample4_9_0_, sampledata0_.sname as sname2_9_0_, sampledata0_.svalue as svalue3_9_0_ from sample_meta_data sampledata0_ where sampledata0_.idsample=?
13:06:53,324 INFO  [stdout] (http-/172.29.250.43:8080-7) Hibernate: select sampledata0_.idsample as idsample4_10_1_, sampledata0_.id as id1_9_1_, sampledata0_.id as id1_9_0_, sampledata0_.idsample as idsample4_9_0_, sampledata0_.sname as sname2_9_0_, sampledata0_.svalue as svalue3_9_0_ from sample_meta_data sampledata0_ where sampledata0_.idsample=?
```

Internally hibernate suppose to use `System.out.println`. Then Will it consume more memory? How `format_sql` and `show_sql` working internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `true` for `show_sql` and `format_sql` will not consume more memory but they will write the `SQL` statements to console so it is time consuming.

From [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional):

> Write all SQL statements to console. This is an alternative to setting
>   the log category org.hibernate.SQL to debug.
>
> e.g. true | false

So when you set the property `show_sql` to `true` then hibernate prints the SQL statement to console using below method:

Hibernate uses below method for displaying the SQL statement from [SQLStatementLogger class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/3.3.2/org/hibernate/jdbc/util/SQLStatementLogger.java#SQLStatementLogger.logStatement%28java.lang.String%2Corg.hibernate.jdbc.util.FormatStyle%29) that it uses internally.

```
/**
 * Log a SQL statement string.
 *
 * @param statement The SQL statement.
 * @param style The requested formatting style.
 */
public void logStatement(String statement, FormatStyle style) {
    if ( log.isDebugEnabled() || logToStdout ) {
        style = determineActualStyle( style );
        statement = style.getFormatter().format( statement );
    }
    log.debug( statement );
    if ( logToStdout ) {
        System.out.println( "Hibernate: " + statement );
    }
}
```

In the above method if the `format_sql`  is set to `true` then the SQL statement will be formatted or else the formatting style will not be applied.

Now if the LOG level is set to `DEBUG` then the SQL statement is written to log file. If you set the `show_sql` to true then it prints the message to console. As mentioned in the link provided in your question, using `System.out.println` is more time consuming compared to printing data to log file.

In general when the application is in production then the log level will not be set to `DEBUG` as writing messages to log files takes some time.

Comment: " will write the SQL statements to console." But It also take some millisecond to write.

Comment: @ashokhein, updated my answer with more details to make it clear, please check.

Answer (score 0):

When show_sql is ture, statements will be printed into system.out; and if you want to statements printed into the file log4j set, you should set the level of log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL to DEBUG