# How can I log Hibernate sql statements in a log file instead of console

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I need to log Hibernate sql statement into a log file instead of console.
I'm using spring boot JPA. and:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.path=/logs
```

Comment: You can refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate

Comment: @FarrukhAhmed unfortunately this question/answers don't address writing to log file instead of console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add following lines to the configuration please([How to log SQL statements in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118683/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-spring-boot))

```
#show sql statement
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
#show sql values
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

spring.jpa.show-sql causees that statements are logged into stdout [Hibernate show sql is equal to Stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015852/hibernate-show-sql-is-equal-to-stdout)

If you want a different file for Hibernate logs, you could add logback.xml. and define a file appender for org.hibernate logger

```
<configuration>
     <appender name="fileAppender"
                  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${DEV_HOME}/[yourlognamefile].log</file>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>
    
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- rollover daily -->
                <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/[yourlognamefile].%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
    
        </appender>
    
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />
         <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

For more information, you could have a look at:
https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot