# Why is System.out.println bad?

Tags: pmd

When i run my PMD plugin they say `System.out.println` has been used. why is `System.out.println` bad to use and is it a defect when using PMD plugin? and what is the alternative way of over coming this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logger vs. System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750346/logger-vs-system-out-println)

Comment: How is it a defect? You need to be a little more specific.

Comment: It's a defect because you have a rule enabled that checks for `System.out.println()`. You can suppress the warnings in the places where you think you need output using the methods described on the following page: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/suppressing.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.out.println..

> are usually intended for debugging purposes and can remain in the
>   codebase even in production code. By using a logger one can
>   enable/disable this behaviour at will (and by priority) and avoid
>   clogging the Standard out log.

<sup>(from [SourceMeter Java user guide](https://www.sourcemeter.com/resources/java) under "Java Logging Rules")</sup>

Import needed (.jar)

[Logger site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

**Example:**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

class Foo{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
    public void testA () {
        System.out.println("Entering test");
        // Better use this
        LOG.info("Entering test");
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, you are asking a question and after some seconds answer to it? good

Comment: Why you opened a bounty to the question when you have the accepted answer? Surprising !

Comment: Wrap the LOG.info("xyz") line with if(LOG.isInfoEnabled()) { ... } so that any string building/appending within the LOG.info call is not processed if the info logging level is not enabled.

Comment: So is there a way to boost rep by doing this? I only ask because I think some of the other answers are better than yours.

Comment: But you still not answered why PMD show sysout as defect

Comment: @Admit It is just fine to ask and answer at exactly the same time. There's even an interface for it. But the question must still meet quality standards.

Comment: @MadPhysicist See my above comment.

Comment: What about CLI apps? The usually output to stdout.

Answer (score 8):

A logger can be turned ON/OFF using a configuration but `System.out.println` cannot be. Importantly loggers provide different levels of logging and again can be controlled through a configuration file.

Also using loggers you can configure rotation, purging etc but cannot do the same for sysout. This is useful especially in a production environment, executing a lot of code, and generating a lot of logging.

Comment: What about CLI apps? The usually output to stdout. That is the normal outout of those type of apps.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova In CLI app u can either use macros or simple if/else to decide log or not to log according to a runtime param

Comment: I mean, if `System.out.println()` is outlawed, what would be the mean for CLI apps to write to the screen?

Answer (score 5):

`System.out.println()` is considered bad practice for Logging.
Because of

- No ability to turn it (`ON`/`OFF`)
- No ability to set output levels (`TRACE`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`),
  without having to recompile your code

Another disadvantage is that the standard output of a program can be redirected, for instance and it's not always clear where the output is actually going, for instance if you do this:

```
java SomeClass > someFile
```

In this case the use of a logging API will help you.

But there are situations where you genuinely want to print something to the standard output too, for those occasions there is `java.io.Console`, which cannot be redirected, so if you're running a command line java program, it gives you confidence that the users are seeing the messages intended to them.

Comment: What about the normal output of a a CLI app? Those app usuarlly write to stdout and that is not considered logging.

Comment: For that, use System.console(), as it allows you to figure out if you're in a terminal or not, as well as it's more fitting to be used by an user.

Comment: Ran `System.console().printf("Hello %s", "world");` in Eclipse and I get NullPointerException. Doc says _"If no console device is available then an invocation of that method will return null. "_

Comment: That is considered a bug in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Answer (score 2):

Printing excessive amounts of into to System.out can become a performance bottleneck because it is synchronized, code from PrintStream:

```
public void println(float x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because, PMD defines a java logging rule named `SystemPrintln` which detects `System.out.println` in the code and consider as a defect.

Since: PMD 2.1

System.(out|err).print is used, consider using a logger.

This rule is defined by the following XPath expression:

```
//Name[
    starts-with(@Image, 'System.out.print')
    or
    starts-with(@Image, 'System.err.print')
    ]
```

And you should be able to modify above XPath expression to override the behavior( I am not sure though)
Below link should give you more insight,

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.6/rules/logging-java.html