# Logger or System.out to show responses of a command line java app

Tags: java, java.util.logging, system.out

I am writing a command line java application for a task of converting the content of a file to a json file. In here I want to get the response whether the operation is successful or not printed in the command line. For this I have two options,

1. To use System.out.println (sout)
2. To use a logger (eg:- java.util.logging.Logger)

I find the response shown in command line when using `sout` is more clear since it does not show texts related to logging (as an example INFO: My response message).

On the other hand I got to know that using `sout` is not a good practice (See Sonar rule [java:s106](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-106)).

I want to know which way is better and why?

Here is my code in the main method with the logger approach.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Executor executor = ExecutorFactory.getExecutor(args);
            executor.execute();
        } catch (ExecutorException e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Let's say `e.getMessage()` gives "No matching file found" as the result.

This is what I get as the response in the command line.

```
INFO: No matching file found
```

I would like it to be more clean. This is what I expect.

```
No matching file found
```

Should I use `sout` for this purpose or is there another way?

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: "Better" for what?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750346/logger-vs-system-out-println) helps

Comment: Why do you think that using standard out is bad practice?

Comment: And why not `System.err` for error messages?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Better for displaying response message to the user?

Comment: Response messages are not logs. In this case printing to stdout is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to output some information in the commond line ,you can simply use `sout`. But if you want to display prompt information at different levels, `logger` is better. In enterprise development, we only use `log.info() log.err()` Using too much `sout` will make code redundant. But you said it's just a command line java application, so I think both is ok.